# How to stop photos taken in Notes being saved in Photo library?

Tags: iphone, ios, notes.app

I mostly work with Notes app in iOS and every time when I capture an image from Note app specific camera, it saves in Photo library. So after making a note I have to delete few images every time to clean my library. So is there any way of stopping that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. That is possible in iOS 10 or later version ( I think). However to do that simply you have to turn off a specific option provided in Notes settings.

**Method**

Goto Settings -> Notes

Then turn off Save Media to Photos. That will solve your problem.

Comment: I cannot find settings in notes app?

Comment: Not in Notes app. Just goto Settings in iOS.